# htaccess www redirect not working correctly?

Tags: 6, .htaccess

I have this line in my htaccess file:

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$ [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

And it works for the most part. But if you go to www.mysite.com/pagetitle, it redirects you to mysite.com/index.php?q=pagetitle. Why would it not redirect you to mysite.com/pagetitle? Is there another portion of code I need to insert into the htaccess file? I do already have search engine-friendly URLs enabled.

Comment: I'm wondering why you have not marked the answer as an accepted answer while it seems correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RewriteConditions says if starting with www.mysite.com then redirect to http://mysite.com

This rule is not affecting clean urls. Clean urls must enabled at http://mysite.com/admin/settings/clean-urls